# python regex to remove and obtain required string

Tags: python, regex

Using regex i need to filter the following random input:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Python34/abcd.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

to

```
C:/Python34/abcd.txt
```

How can i do in regex to abtain the selected portion?

Comment: Is the input really random or is it always some form of xml? `ElementTree` would make this simple to parse.

Comment: it is random i mean only the 'C:/ ......txt' changes remaining are same!

Comment: Then you could simply use `re.search("name='(.+?)'", text).group(1)`. Did you even read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) on regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this using regex, you can use the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Python34/abcd.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
>>> re.search(r"<[^>]*\bname='([^']*)", s).group(1)
'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'
```

**Explanation:**

This matches a beginning bracket, everything up to `name` and captures whats inside single quotes. A word boundary `\b` does not consume any characters, it asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

```
<         # '<'
[^>]*     # any character except: '>' (0 or more times)
\b        # the boundary between a word character (\w) and not a word character
name='    # 'name=\''
(         # group and capture to \1:
  [^']*   #   any character except: ''' (0 or more times)
)         # end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookbehind also. It matches the string which was just after to `name='` upto the next `'` symbol.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Python34/abcd.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
>>> m = re.search(r"(?<=name=\')[^\']*", s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fa131e6f370>
>>> m.group()
'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this isn't random, but here you go:

```
import re
string = "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Python34/abcd.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
regexString = r'<\S+ \s+ name=\'(?P<name>.*?)\'.*?>'
regex       = re.compile(regexString, re.X)
match       = regex.match(string)
if match != None:
    myName = match.group('name')
```

Comment: You should never use `string` as a variable name in python, not even in an example. Besides that, why do you want to match the whole line? It just makes the regex harder, and you're practically guaranteed that there will be only one 'name' attribute in a xml tag. There's also no reason to use the X flag. And as a last thing you should probably be using try/except instead of `if match != None`, because you expect the match to (almost) never fail.

Comment: `string` isn't a big deal, `str` would be. X flag is used because I provided spaces in my example and X is used for `verbose`, as you said to the OP already, and I quote ` Did you even read the documentation on regexes?`

Comment: It's not a *big* deal, no, but it's still not something that should ever be done, and its use should therefore also not be promoted in examples. I do know what the X flag does, or else I wouldn't comment about it. However, I think that complicating your code with that flag just so you can add two (unnecessary) spaces is not a good idea. You quoted part of my comment. Don't you agree with me though that this question would be completely unnecessary if OP had just read the docs?